# React routing to specific page not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to redirect to product page after successful login but I'm getting errors, none of the solutions I've searched seem to work. I've already tried **useHistory, Redirect, withRouter,etc**. The version of router is: *"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"* and I use webPack for testing. Here are the following files:

**Routes.js**
//all imports done

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <div>
        <NavBar/>
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact={true}/>
        <Route path="/ChangeContext" component={ChangeContext}/> 
        <Route path="/Products" component={Products}/> 
        <Route path="/Login" component={Login}/> 
        <Route path="/NotFound" component={NotFound}/>         
        </Switch>
        </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

**NavBar**

```
<header>
        <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="is-active" exact={true}>Home &nbsp;</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/Products" activeClassName="is-active" >Products &nbsp;</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/Login" activeClassName="is-active" >Login &nbsp;</NavLink>
        <br></br>
        </header>
```

**Login.js**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Login=()=>{

    const history = useHistory();
    const handleSubmit=e=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let username=e.target.username.value;
        let password=e.target.password.value;
        let uname=localStorage.getItem("username");
        let pwd=localStorage.getItem("password")
        if((username===uname && password===pwd)&&(uname!="" && pwd!="")){
            history.push("/Products");
        }
        else{
            console.log("Try Again!",uname)
            
        }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.useHistory) is not a function
    at Login (Login.js?d1d6:8)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js?cada:14985)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js?cada:17811)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:19049)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?cada:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?cada:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?cada:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js?cada:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:22779)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js?cada:22707)
```

Comment: From where are you importing useHistory hook?

Comment: @ Nacho Zullo from "react-router-dom";

Comment: Can you verify that the currently install version of `react-router-dom` is actually >5.1 by running `npm list react-router-dom`? That error makes is sound like the package does not have hooks included.

Comment: What version of react are you using?

Comment: @ Brian Thompson , when I ran the command, I got this o/p: npm ERR! invalid: react-router-dom@4.3.1, but in package.json file it's react-router-dom": "^5.1.2

Comment: @Nacho Zullo  version  "react": "^17.0.1"

Comment: There's your problem then, You have the wrong version of the package installed.

Comment: Check your `package.json` that the version of `react-router-dom` I think it is a problem in the version.

Comment: try deleting node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and then run npm install

Comment: Simply run `npm install`, you only need to delete node_modules or the lock file as a last resort if it doesn't work, but it should. `npm update` will also work and will update all pacakges to the most recent versions allowed by your package.json

Comment: Just uninstall `react-router-dom` and try npm install `react-router-dom@4.3.1`

Comment: @PulsaraSandeepa Why would you recommend installing an older version in favor of the updated one? And most importantly, <5.1 will not have the hooks they are trying to use - the whole reason for this question.

Comment: @Brian Thompson Thanks! Finally it works, couldn't believe it was a version problem.

Comment: Thanks @Nacho Zullo for your help as well!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import `{useHistory}`.

Simply keep `props` as a parameter in the main component function and then use `props.history.push('/Products')`.

You can also do `window.href.location="/Products"` but this will cause the page to reload.

Comment: This may be true, but it just avoids the problem. They need to fix their dependency issue.

Comment: yeah that's true but for someone who needs immediate fix can use this.

Answer (score -1):

```
//History.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();

//your component
import History from './History';

History.push('Products')
```

Comment: This is so missleading answer. OP suppose to use `useHistory` hook from `react-router-dom` to work with the history. There is no need to reinvent the wheel, just reuse once written.